# Getting Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) while printing tree

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

I was trying to solve this problem

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/construct-an-expression-tree/1?utm_source=gfgpractice#

Problem: To create expression tree for given postfix expression

My Approach: I tried to maintain a stack of nodes and generated a tree using general postfix evaluation approach where the resultant for the given operator would be the node itself but with modified left and right pointers.

But I'm getting error.

```
Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
Learn More about
Seg Fault
```

```
// { Driver Code Starts
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct et
{
    char value;
    et* left, *right;
    
    et(char x){
        value = x;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
};

bool isOperator(char c)
{
    if (c == '+' || c == '-' ||
            c == '*' || c == '/' ||
            c == '^')
        return true;
    return false;
}

void inorder(et *t)
{
    if(t)
    {
        inorder(t->left);
        printf("%c ", t->value);
        inorder(t->right);
    }
}

et* constructTree(char []);

int main()
{   
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
    char postfix[25];
    cin>>postfix;
    et* r = constructTree(postfix);
    inorder(r);
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
}// } Driver Code Ends


/*struct et
{
    char value;
    et* left, *right;
};*/

//function to construct expression tree
et* constructTree(char postfix[])
{
//code here
    stack<et> operand;
    et *root=NULL;
    for(int i=0;postfix[i] != '\0';++i){
        if(postfix[i]>='a' && postfix[i]<='z'){
            et node = et(postfix[i]);
            //cout<<node.value<<" "<<node.left<<" "<<node.right<<"\n";
            operand.push(node);
            /*et nod = operand.top();
            cout<<nod.value<<" "<<nod.left<<" "<<nod.right<<"\n";
            operand.pop();
            operand.push(nod);
            et *no = &(operand.top());
            cout<<no->value<<" "<<no->left<<" "<<no->right<<'\n';*/
        }
        else{
            et right1=operand.top();
            operand.pop();
            et left1=operand.top();
            operand.pop();
            et node = (et(postfix[i]));
            node.left = &left1;
            node.right= &right1;
            operand.push(node);
            root=&(operand.top());
            //cout<<node.value<<" "<<node.left<<" "<<node.right<<"\n";
            //inorder(root);
        }
    }
    //root=NULL;
    return root;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what to do so that I won't get an error ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here
`node.left = &left1;`

`left1` is a local variable and will be destroyed. So after that you're accessing an invalid address.

You can use something like this
`node.left = new er(left1);`

but you should prefer to store pointers in stack at first.

Answer (score 0):

In function `constructTree`, you do not do any dynamic memory allocations.
So whatever memory pointer you return from that function, is pointing to an invalid memory by the time you're outside the function.